# Braintree: Authorization Error when creating or updating a customer with a CVV verification in Sandbox mode

Tags: ios, node.js, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using `Braintree` as a payment gateway of my iOS app.
I created a Node.js server to process the payment.
I want to create customers with the customer id of the user id used in the user management system.

```
BraintreeGateway.customer.update(req.uid, {
  paymentMethodNonce,
  verifyCard: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
  } else {
    if (result.success) {
      req.customer = result.customer
      console.info('Payment Method:', result.customer.paymentMethods[0])
      res.send({
        status: HttpStatus.OK,
        message: 'Successfully updated!'
      })
    } else {
      next({
        error: 'Failed to update a payment method!',
        result
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Here `req.uid` is the unique identifier of the user.
It is working well without CVV verification settings enabled in the Braintree Control Panel. [Here](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/~/processing)
But with the CVV verification settings enabled, I get `authorizationError: Authorization Error` which means the invalid API key.[Here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/node#authorization-error)
I am using `DropIn UI` to input credit card and passing the `paymentMethodNonce` to the server properly.
The current test credit card number is Number: `4242 4242 4242 4242` Exp: `12/2019` CVV: `123`.

What is the mistake here? Will it work in the production mode? (Braintree will accept the valid credit card numbers in the production mode? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It's likely that the user you are using to perform the update API call does not have the correct permissions to perform card verifications. I recommend checking the user's role and making sure it has all the necessary permissions: https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/basics/users-roles#creating-and-editing-roles

If after doing this you still receive an authorization error, I recommend reaching out to Braintree [support.](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)